# how to log off all users who are logged in to my site-php

Tags: php

hi is there a way I can unset the sessions of all the users who are logged in to my site. I need this for my admin panel, wherein we might want to logout all the users loggedin while we put up the site for maintenance.

Edit: The Sessions are stored on the filesystem in the /tmp folder. Yes clearing that directory was an option but do we have any other way .

Comment: It is almost certainly possible, but since you haven't given us so much as a clue about how your login system is implemented, we can't tell you how.

Comment: I don't see the need to log users out just because the site goes in to maintenance mode; you would just display an "in maintenance" message in response to *any* request.

Comment: Where are you storing the sessions? On a database, as cookies? You need to provide more details please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use cookie based session delete all session files in the folder where you store them.
If you store user sessions in the database, then just delete all records.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [session_set_save_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) with database set as a sessions storage, you can delete all rows from sessions table.